# How to get the json data from an external file using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json

I have followed this [url](http://jsfiddle.net/JYS8n/2/).Here I'm writing the data variable  and assigning the data  in the directive itself.

But I've json data in the separate sample.json file.Then how to get the sample.json data  into the angular directive.Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue...

My js:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('multiLine', [
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        data: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element) {


var data = [
    {
        "City": "New York",
        "Data": [
            {
                "Date": "20111001",
                "Value": "63.4"
            },
            {
                "Date": "20111002",
                "Value": "58.0"
            },
            {
                "Date": "20111003",
                "Value": "53.3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "City": "San Francisco",
        "Data": [
            {
                "Date": "20111001",
                "Value": "62.7"
            },
            {
                "Date": "20111002",
                "Value": "59.9"
            },
            {
                "Date": "20111003",
                "Value": "59.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "City": "Austin",
        "Data": [
            {
                "Date": "20111001",
                "Value": "72.2"
            },
            {
                "Date": "20111002",
                "Value": "67.7"
            },
            {
                "Date": "20111003",
                "Value": "69.4"
            }
        ]
    }
];

var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 80,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
},
width = 560 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function (d) {
    return x(d.Date);
})
    .y(function (d) {
    return y(d.Value);
});

var svg = d3.select(element[0]).append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

color.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.City; }));

data.forEach(function (kv) {
    kv.Data.forEach(function (d) {
        d.Date = parseDate(d.Date);
    });
});

var cities = data;

var minX = d3.min(data, function (kv) { return d3.min(kv.Data, function (d) { return d.Date; }) });
var maxX = d3.max(data, function (kv) { return d3.max(kv.Data, function (d) { return d.Date; }) });
var minY = d3.min(data, function (kv) { return d3.min(kv.Data, function (d) { return d.Value; }) });
var maxY = d3.max(data, function (kv) { return d3.max(kv.Data, function (d) { return d.Value; }) });

x.domain([minX, maxX]);
y.domain([minY, maxY]);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Temperature (ºF)");

var city = svg.selectAll(".city")
    .data(cities)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "city");

city.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", function (d) {
    return line(d.Data);
})
    .style("stroke", function (d) {
    return color(d.City);
});

city.append("text")
    .datum(function (d) {
    return {
        name: d.City,
        date: d.Data[d.Data.length - 1].Date,
        value: d.Data[d.Data.length - 1].Value
    };
})
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
    return "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," + y(d.value) + ")";
})
    .attr("x", 3)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function (d) {
        return d.name;
});
 }
    };
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for that. Example:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url:'path/to/file.json'})
    .then(
        function(json) {
            console.log('result: ', json);
        },
        function(error) {
            Console.warn('An error occured');
        }
    );
```

You can also use `$http.get` as a convenience function.

Answer (score 0):

Inject `$http` into your directive:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('multiLine', ['$http', function($http) {
```

Use it's `get` method to fetch the file:

```
$http.get('file.json').then(
    function resolved (response) {
        console.info('Resolved at ' + new Date());
        // response.data holds your JSON object
    },
    function rejected (response) {
        console.error('Rejected at ' + new Date());
    }
);
```

Reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the JSON Object from other file you can use the http Get Method as follows:

```
app.controller("testController", function($scope, $http) {
   $scope.data= [];
      $http.get('data.json').success(function(data) { 
         $scope.data = data.value;
         console.log(data.value);
      });    
});
```

Check this link : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these methods will throw $http/legacy error. See: [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice)

Comment: Oh okay. I didn't know about that the $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated cause we still used it. Thanks for that useful information.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here I created sample for how to get data from external json.
```

[Sample Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/5db4HILOBEWnybBiSwM8?p=info)

```
myApp.factory('Data', ['$http', function($http) {
   var dataFactory = {};
    dataFactory.getdata = function () {
              return $http.get('your.json');
        };
    return dataFactory;
}]);

myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', function( $scope, Data ){
    Data.getdata().then(function (data) {
        $scope.Data = data.data;
  });
});
```